# FreeRADIUS - Allow some navigation before authentication

Tags: node.js, networking, radius, freeradius

i'm thinking of using radius in an open network to allow some navigation in a some local pages, and require authentication for Internet access, ¿is there any way to configure FreeRADIUS in that way?
For example, have a NodeJS app and FreeRADUIS running in an ubuntu server, when a user connects to the network, redirect to a page that let's him use the NodeJS app, or sign in for Internet use

Answer (score 1):

FreeRADIUS just sends back Attribute/Value pairs. If there's attributes supported by your access point vendor which allow you to do this, then sure, but there are no official RFC attributes for defining per session ACLs or redirect rules.